# <div> getting posted inside of a <ul>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using a fetch to gather data from a SharePoint form that's data is currently stored in a SharePoint list, and I am posting it to an HTML page.

In my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vg9obeys/5/), the actual output is my expected output which is perfect. The data is appended to a `<ul>` inside of a `<li>`(this has to do with the data being a string and not being pulled through fetch[I am assuming]).

The issue I am facing with the fetch is that the data getting pulled through, instead of posting directly to the `<ul>`, it is posting to a `<div>` inside of the `<ul>`, which if I remember correctly, `<div>` elements are not permitted within a `<ul>`.

1.) Why is the data getting posted inside of `<ul><div> </div></ul>`? Is it because the column on the form corresponding with the data is "Multiple lines of text entry"?

2.) What is the best way to go about correcting this?

Here is a screenshot of how it is posting:
[image]

In the inspect element, this is how it says it is posting:

```
<h4> Training </h4>
<ul>- 
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
</ul>
```

Finally, here is a snippet of my JS/HTML.

```js
function loadData(url) {
    url = partUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=Deliverables,MajorTasks,Actions,Support,Resource,Team,Training,Upcoming,WeekOf,Travel";
    return fetch(url, { headers: { accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" } }) // make request
      .then((r) => {
        if (!r.ok) throw new Error("Failed: " + url);  // Check for errors
        return r.json();  // parse JSON
      })
      .then((data) => data.d.results);
  }
  loadData()
    .then((results) => {
        const data = results;
        var listContent = '';
              
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         listContent += '<li data-weekOf="'+data[i].WeekOf+'">';
         listContent += '<h2>' + data[i].Team  +'</h2>';
         listContent += '<h4> Tasks </h4>';
         if(data[i].MajorTasks !== null){
            listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].MajorTasks + '</ul>';
         }else{
              listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Deliverables Submitted</h4>';
                 if(data[i].DeliverablesSubmitted !== null){
         listContent += '<ul><li>' + "- " + data[i].DeliverablesSubmitted + '</li></ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Personnel Actions </h4>';
                 if(data[i].PersonnelActions !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].PersonnelActions + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Upcoming Events </h4>';
                 if(data[i].Upcoming !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Upcoming + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Training </h4>';
         if(data[i].Training !== null){
                 listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Training + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Resource Request </h4>';
         if(data[i].ResourceRequest !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].ResourceRequest + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Support Request </h4>';
         if(data[i].SupportRequest !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].SupportRequest + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '<h4> Travel/ODCs </h4>';
         if(data[i].TravelODC !== null){
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].TravelODC + '</ul>';
         }else{
         listContent += '<ul>' + "- There were no notes attached to this section." + '</ul>';
         }
         listContent += '</li>';
 }
   $('#report-summary').html(listContent);
   $('#under_txt').text(' ');
  });
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#under_txt').text(value);
    $('li').fadeOut(10);
    $('[data-weekOf='+value+']').fadeIn();
  });
  
});
function sortNewestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);
 }
function sortOldestFirst(){
  var elements = $('[data-weekOf]');
  elements.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date($(a).attr('data-weekOf')) - new Date($(b).attr('data-weekOf'));
  });
  $('#report-summary').html(elements);

}
$("#btn").click(function () {
$("#printarea").printThis();
});
```

```css
.container h2{
 text-align: left;
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.container h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.container ul {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}
.container li{
    list-style-type: none !important;
}
span{
  font-size: 15px !important;
}
#report-summary{
  margin-left: 15px !important;
  margin-right: 15px !important;
}
#search{
  text-align: center !important;
}
p {
  text-align: center !important;
}
.container h4{
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: black;
}
#myInput{
  text-align: center !important;
}
#under_txt{
margin-left: 5px !important;
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/printThis/1.15.0/printThis.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
<div id="search">
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for Week Of">
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="Print">
<div id="printarea">
<h1>
Weekly Manager Report
</h1>
<p>Week Of<span id="under_txt"></span></p>
<ul id="report-summary">

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the "Permitted content" on the `ul` documentation  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul). I suspect this might be because you are outputting `<ul>text</ul>` instead of `<ul><li>text</li></ul>`. Edit: although looking through your JS, are you sure `data[i].Training` is something like `text` and not `<div>text</div>`? Because you're concatenating the value right in, this could also be the cause of the unexpected output. Have you tried step debugging this with breakpoints or inspecting the values in JS (console.log, or otherwise)?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I tried your first comment, ```listContent += '<ul>' + '<li>' + "- " + data[i].DeliverablesSubmitted + '</li>' + '</ul>';``` and it is still outputting the same way

Comment: "it is still outputting the same way" - so it's still outputting `<ul>- <div>text</div></ul>`? Or is it actually outputting `<ul><li>- <div>text</div></li></ul>`? If it's the latter, then I bet `data[i].DeliverablesSubmitted` contains a wrapping `div`.

Comment: The first (Tasks)  is returning like so ```<ul><li>- 
  <ul>
    <li>Test Plan</li>
    <li>Security Plan</li>
    <li>Computer Plan</li>
  </ul>
</li></ul>``` and then the other task is returning like so ```<ul><li>- 
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
</li></ul>```

Comment: A couple other minor things - you're first initializing `var listContent = [];` as an array, but then you use it as a string. I'd suggest changing that to `var listContent = '';`. Also, after your `for` loop, `listContent` is a string with a bunch of `li` nodes: `<li data-weekOf=...></li><li data-weekOf=...></li>`, but you're adding that to `$('#report-summary').html(listContent);`. But your HTML is `<div id="report-summary">`, so you're ending up with `<div><li></li><li></li></div>` I'd recommend changing that `div` to a `ul`, or outputting separate `ul` inside of the `div` instead of `li`s.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones see my most recent edit, I changed everything you mentioned, and nothing was changed.

Comment: You're missing the most important part of the update, which [the answer below reiterates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054196/1499877). The JSON data is probably is in the format `<div>text</div>`, not just `text`, so you need to parse that out somehow before adding it to your `<li>`. I'd probably write that into a separate function so you can do `listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + removeTags(data[i].TravelODC) + '</ul>';`. It will keep the code cleaner and centralize the functionality. Or `listContent += addListAndRemoveTags(data[i].TravelODC);` and put all the functionality there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lazy way of solving this would be to strip out any associated HTML SharePoint might be passing down.
Change your `<ul>` lines from something like this

```
  listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Travel + '</ul>';
```

to this:

```
  listContent += '<ul>' + "- " + data[i].Travel.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, "") + '</ul>';
```

That replace syntax is taken from this article on stripping tags:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/